# In Java 8, using lambdas, how can i groupby my List in this specific case?

Tags: java, list, lambda

i have a list containing an Entity Object, that i transform into a DTO object using lambdas. However, due to the initial query, i have duplicate records, so i wanted to use groupingBy, however i couldn't find any examples that do this after using .map(). 
Here's my code using placeholders for the class names:

```
public static List<EntityDTO> of(List<Entity> dealEvents) {
        List<EntityDTO> result;

              result = dealEvents.stream()
                       .map(s -> DealFactory.ofEntity(s)).collect(Collectors.toList());

        return result;
```

The ofEntity method instantiates a new EntityDTO for each record. I want to groupby a specific field of EntityDTO, which is orderNumber. How can i achieve this by integrating it into this code?

Comment: "however i couldn't find any examples that do this after using .map()" <--- it works exactly the same way whether or not you use `map`.

Answer (score 2):

`groupingBy` is a `Collector` you need to pass to the `collect` method, not the method itself

```
result = dealEvents.stream()
    .map(s -> DealFactory.ofEntity(s))
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(EntityDTO::getOrderNumber));
```